# What to do to migrate own question to another site?

Tags: discussion, migration

Consider this post: *[Generate rewrite rules based on database value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134203/generate-rewrite-rules-based-on-databse-value)*. I asked the question on Stack Overflow erroneously, but I want it to migrate to *[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

I have already raised a flag for moderator's attention to migrate this question. Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, the process to migrate is to flag for moderator attention

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks for quick assurance.

Comment: As stated in the possible dupe: *"If you don't have 3,000 reputation, the site isn't in the list of available migration targets, or the question got closed without being migrated, do not fret. You can also flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you."*